# How to filterout a type from a rosbag record?

Tags: ros, filter, ros-melodic, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have on my hands a 18GiB rosbag that contains multiple topics of PointCloud2 type. From my experience those are the main contributors to the rosbags' size. After the bag is recorded I can use the following to throw away the PointCloud2 messages:
`rosbag filter big.bag small.bag "'PointCloud2' not in str(type(m))"` but what flag to `rosbag record` should I use to not record them?

I know `rosbag record -x` but according to documentation that only works with regexes and my PointCloud2 topics have different names.

By default I use `rosbag record -a` since the PointCloud2 topics are only a fraction of what I want to record.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376769/how-to-filterout-a-type-from-a-rosbag-record?/) by [Aleksander Bobiński](https://answers.ros.org/users/71150/aleksander-bobi%C5%84ski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2021-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Somewhat guided by gvdhoorn's answer I wrote the following shell wrapper around rosbag record.

```
unwanted_type=PointCloud2
unwanted_topics_as_regex_alternative=$(rostopic list --verbose | grep $unwanted_type | cut -d '[' -f 1 | cut -d '*' -f2- | sed -E 's/^ (.*) $/\1/g' | tr '\n' '|')
rosbag record -a -x "($unwanted_topics_as_regex_alternative)"
```

---

Originally posted by [Aleksander Bobiński](https://answers.ros.org/users/71150/aleksander-bobi%C5%84ski/) with karma: 26 on 2021-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-04-24**:
Nice idea to use `rostopic` in a shell script wrapper. Would `rostopic list` with `rostopic type` be less `--verbose`?

**Comment by [Aleksander Bobiński](https://answers.ros.org/users/71150/aleksander-bobi%C5%84ski/) on 2021-04-24**:
I think one would have to use a for loop since `rostopic type` does not accept multiple topic names as arguments. Maybe if `rostopic type` would accept topic names from `stdin` this could be done in one line without the `cut` tricks by piping from `rostopic list` to `rostopic type` to `grep`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-04-24**:\

> Maybe if `rostopic type` would accept topic names from `stdin` this could be done in one line without the `cut` tricks by piping from `rostopic list` to `rostopic type` to `grep`.

afaik, it does support that.

**Comment by [Aleksander Bobiński](https://answers.ros.org/users/71150/aleksander-bobi%C5%84ski/) on 2021-04-24**:
Are you sure? For me `echo "/velodyne_points" | rostopic type` results in:

```
rostopic type: error: the following arguments are required: topic_or_field
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-04-24**:
You can do it with `xargs`: `rostopic list | xargs -i rostopic type {}`. But you don't really gain anything doing this I believe.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't believe `rosbag` supports this directly. `-x` works with topic *names*, not types. `-a` will record *everything*.

You could take a look at [the rosbag API](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Cookbook), which would make this not too difficult (ie: retrieve a list of all recorded topics, prune those with a specific type), but that wouldn't prevent them from being recorded first. You'd be post-processing an already recorded `.bag`.

Another option (which would require some work): write a wrapper which uses the [ROS Master API](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Master_API) to get a list of all topics, filters them based on type, then spits out a list of topic names which don't carry msgs of that type and then you can pass those to `rosbag record`. This would prevent topics you're not interestd in from being recorded.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-04-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1